# Toggle gps on root android devices

Tags: android, gps, root, su

There is an old question about it ([Toggle gps on root devices on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373234/toggle-gps-on-root-devices-on-android))....

I really need enable GPS using a su command without any notification ... 
My code is above:

```
public static void turnOnGPS(){

    try {
        String mCommand = "adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed gps,network,wifi ";
        Shell.runAsRoot(mCommand);
        Utilities.log("GPS Actioned.");

    }catch (Exception o){
        Utilities.log(o.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck show notifications from su Settings tab

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution..... I did the following:

1. I rooted my device
2. I installed my app as system app, it's simple, just copy your apk
   into /system/priv-app/myApk.apk and set chmod 644 permissions. If
   you have a doubt, check this post
   ([If i set my android app to a system app, after a factory reset, will it be removed from the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458415/if-i-set-my-android-app-to-a-system-app-after-a-factory-reset-will-it-be-remov)).
3. I **just** removed the /system/app/SuperSU folder
4. I did a factory reset on device, and that is it ..... =D