# How to make an anti lost app run even after phone hard reset?

Tags: android, reset, rooted-device

Well guys... Phone losting and phone stealing is very very increased now days .. the anti lost apps works only if the internet connected and location on... When the device has it's data... But what if the thief reset the phone from recovery mode ? There's no way to trace it....so my target is too keep an anti lost app installed even after the hard reset.. .well i don't know any kinda coding.. but with some basic core knowledge I came to know about the partitions of android... And also came to know that the system partition keep the system apps and os...so unlike pc we don't have to install the os after formatting the phone.......  So I'm thinking to keep an anti lost app in system partition... So that even a thief gets my phone and reset it from recovery mode... Still the app will remain installed and i would able to find my device... Well I surfed in internet.. and it's can only be done with root access... But... How far i know... The app would install even after the phone reset but how can i keep the app data... Cuz you have to login in any kinda anti lost app ... Which auto happens when the data remains in the phone.... So I want to develop an anti lost app which would allow me to access my phone even after hard reset.... can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question itself has the answer... you say ... 
"Im thinking to keep an anti lost app in system partition...." and also know that..

...."and it's can only be done with root access.."

read these do sentences again... you will get your answer...

[also read this article](https://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/)
to get a rough idea of what its all about....

in simple words... to install apps in the SYSTEM PARTITION you will surely NEED A ROOTED PHONE..

also go through [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458415/if-i-set-my-android-app-to-a-system-app-after-a-factory-reset-will-it-be-remov?rq=1) to clear your doubts of apps in the system partition after hard reset of the phone..

Comment: Thank you very much for reply 

Answer (score 0):

For an Android app to persist over factory resets, it (the app) has to be a **system** app and device must be rooted.

Starting from Android 6.0 *(Marshmallow)*, if you place your app on **/system** partition from user-space (by copying into /system/app as root) will prevent the device from booting because of dm-verity enforced. It was there since 4.4 *(Kitkat)* but has been optional. Read [here](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/).

So logically you are out of luck for newer devices unless you are the device vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If you root your phone there are many apps that will allow you to add an app to the system partition and remove apps from the system partition I do it quite often the data part of the question I never really thought of oh and the point of making this statement was because I'm using a pixel 7a on a custom operating system based on Android 13 which is called SuperiorOS....so yes you can add to the system even on the newest phones.....one app you can use to do this is luckypatcher by chelpus it is one of the options it has in its toolbox...mainly it's used to cheat apps and games for free purchases and to remove ads ...most of options in it can be accomplished without root but for what you are asking root will be required make sure where u download it from is actually the real lucky patcher there are many fake luckypatchers out there.... And to root your device i would recommend magisk from GitHub, and for specific information about how to or if it's even possible to root your device id suggest looking up that question on Xda (Google it it will pop up ) xda is the foremost for all things phone mods and such....goodluck...

Comment: Any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).